# Unit Test Class

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage

I am trying to write test data for below code.

```
public List<SelectOption> valuebrand{
get{
        List<SelectOption> brandlist = new List<SelectOption>();
        Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = Product2.Brand.getDescribe();
        List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();
            brandlist.add(new SelectOption('None', 'None'));
        for( Schema.PicklistEntry f : ple)
            brandlist.add(new SelectOption(f.getLabel(), f.getValue()));
        return brandlist;
  }
}
```

I tried below line but no luck. Any Suggestions.

```
List<string> testStringList = Select_PageController.valuebrand;
```

Comment: whats the error you are getting?

Comment: If you're getting an error, Including the error message **verbatim** (i.e. copy and paste the entire error, word for word) is generally helpful. Other than that, including the test class that you have so far is also helpful. You can add both of those to your question if you [edit] it (adding things like code and clarifying statements are better off as edits to your question, rather than comments on the question).

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't very clear. If you are trying to test (and get test coverage) for the `valuebrand` property of your controller you will need code that looks more like this:

```
Select_PageController c = new Select_PageController();
System.assert(c.valuebrand.size() > 0);
```

See e.g. [Testing Custom Controllers and Controller Extensions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_error_handling.htm).